# django-auth: login with user uuid and limit permissions

Tags: django, authentication, django-authentication, django-permissions

I'm trying to create a kind of quick response form where a user does not need to login but is identified with his uuid (in the url). Moreover i need to restrict his permissions for this session so that he only could to a few things.

1. User gets url with UUID and ID of event (Where he can response)
2. User clicks on link and response page opens
3. User is identified via uuid
4. With the id of the event the event response form is generated
5. User can chose options and submit the form
   Normally there are multiple other options (e.g. in the menue) available but these should only be accessible if user identifies with his username and password.

Of course i could write a special view but is there a more elegant way where i could reuse my existing view for the response?

Answer (score 0):

First you'll want to use the UUID to trigger the login.

How you approach this will depend on whether you mind using a specific login url/view or you want people to arrive directly at the intended url/view (just with the UUID parameter). If you use a specific view you'll check the UUID, (presumably mark it as used/expired), then login the user. Alternatively for the UUID to checked and have users login via any url/view, you'll want a to use a custom middleware that's placed ahead of AuthenticationMiddleware in your middleware settings. In each case, once you have the logged in the user, you'll want to store in session some sort of flag to indicate they've auth'd via a temporary login UUID.

Now that you've authenticated and logged in the user via the UUID, it's time to serve them the view. At this point in your View you'll check for presence of the flag in the user session to determine their permissions.

You could go further and create another middleware class to encapsulate the session lookups and add a property, say "is_auth_temporary", to the request.User object that is a sibling to the is_anonymous and is_authenticated property.